# What should be done with the [twitter] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-renaming

The are two questions using the [twitter](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter) tag.

With the rebranding of Twitter to X, what should be done to the [twitter](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter)?

While renaming the tag is a possibility, X, nee Twitter, is also a [social-media](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media) company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make [twitter](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter) a synonym of [social-media](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media).

Answer (score 3):

Leave it alone, there are still many references to twitter on the platform

1. The official URL is still twitter.com
2. x.com just redirects to twitter.com
3. The login still says sign in to twitter
4. The main page still says join twitter
5. The app is still named twitter
6. Many other references to twitter still exist

Also there are likely lawsuits over the name change as META holds a trademark on that for the social media concept.

Until they complete the rebranding and switch everything over to the new name we shouldn't bother doing anything with the tag.